# findOne() or find() are returning null even though an entry exists in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a ToDo List Node app. I am using below code to create a list with a particular title in case it has already not been created and add some default values to it; where as, if it has already been created then a redirect to the page associated with it will be performed and all tasks associated with that list would be displayed on the page.

```
    app.get("/:customListName", function (req, res) {
    const customListName = req.params.customListName;
    List.find({ name: customListName })
    .then((listFound) => {
    if (listFound.length === 0) {
        const list = new List({
        name: customListName,
        items: defaultItems,
    });
       list.save();
       console.log(
         "list with a name of " + customListName + " has been created."
       );
       return res.redirect("/" + list.name);
    } else {
       return res.render("list", {
          listTitle: listFound[0].name,
          newListItems: listFound[0].items,
       });
     }
   })
   .catch((err) => {
       console.log("Error faced while creating new list ===> " + err);
       });
   });
```

However, for the first time - when there is no list with a particular name `listFound`  - it creates a list in MongoDB; despite it, `find()` or even `findOne()`
returns `null` when it runs second time as well, though a value has been added previously.
What is wrong in the code as I am only redirecting it to the associated page right after the list is created **once.**

Answer (score 0):

You are going find debugging your code increasingly difficult as you seem to be conflating your logic by not seperating your HTTP verbs. By that I mean you should handle creating documents with `post` requests and retrieving documents with `get` requests. You can better leverage the express framework by splitting your logic like so:

```
// Use a form or JavaScript to post your new messages to the /list/create route
app.post('/list/create', async (req, res) =>{
   console.log(req.body); //< Make sure data is parsed and present in req.body
   try{
      const {name} = req.body; //< Add other fields you post here too
      const list = await List.create({name}); // Add new document to collection
      return res.redirect("/" + list.name);
   }catch(err){
      console.log("Error faced while creating new list ===> " + err);
      res.status(400).json({
         error : 'Appropriate error message sent to front-end'
      });
   }
});

// Then get your list from the /:customListName
app.get('/:customListName', async (req, res) =>{
   try{
      const name = req.params.customListName;
      const listFound = await List.findOne({name}); //< Use findOne instead if you know you are only looking for one document
      if(listFound){ // listFound will be null if no match
         return res.render("list", {
            listTitle: listFound.name,
            newListItems: listFound.items,
         });
      }else{
         //Decide what to do if no document found i.e. listFound is null
      }
   }catch(err){
      console.log("Error faced while creating new list ===> " + err);
      res.status(400).json({
         error : 'Appropriate error message sent to front-end'
      });
   }
});
```